# VB: Read "x" integer from a string and replace it

Tags: string, vbscript, replace, integer

First of all, I am not from programming background and totally new to VB. For some reasons, I have to do a small scripting task at office.

I have gone through many posts here as well on other forums but not able to find the required information.

Ok so here's what I need to do:

I want to find an integer from a string (the integer can be any from 5 to 4095) and replace it with an integer of my choice.

I have done some analysis but not able to find a function which can search for "any" integer from a string. Searching for fixed integers is working fine.

e.g:

Convert: "There are 10 apples" - where 10 can be any number from 5 to 4095, not known to me.

To: "There are 5 apples" - 5 is the number I will manually give.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit**

Final Code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
strFile = "C:\Users\inkasap\Desktop\temp\IOParams_Backup.xml" 
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile) 
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream strLine = objFile.ReadLine 
    Dim re, strLine 
    Set re = New RegExp 
    if InStr(strLine,"name=""BIOSCUPP") > 0 Then 
        re.Pattern = "\d+" 
        Set colMatch = re.Execute(strLine) 
        For Each objMatch In colMatch 
           strLine = Replace(strLine, objMatch.Value, "30") 
        Next end 
    if WScript.Echo strLine 
Loop
```

Comment: _"For some reasons, I have to do a small **scripting**
 task at office"_ Are you sure you want help with VB.NET rather than VBScript or VBA which are completely different?

Comment: you want to write a macro for word or excel or ... ? And how robust has this to be? I mean, can this happen: "There are10 apples"

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I need help with VBScript (.vbs file).

I want a batch file (which I have already prepared) to run this VBScript and edit a .xml which I have in the same folder.

Comment: Have tagged this vbscript instead of VB.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx#scripting05_topic1) to find any numerical value, and then replace it:

```
Dim re, test
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\d+"

test = "There are 4000 apples"

Set colMatch = re.Execute(test)
For Each objMatch In colMatch
    MsgBox(Replace(test,objMatch.Value,"5"))
Next
```

[image]

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx) page contains all informations you need.

Comment: Thank you. The script is fine. Now I am trying to integrate it into my file and work on my exact requirement. Will ask if I have any further question or will post the results of my work.

Comment: Should I mark it "accepted" now or after I complete my actual task successfully? This is my first post in the forum so don't know exactly. :)

Comment: Ok, I did. :)

However, I have not yet got my exact thing to work. Will ask if needed.

Comment: How to add the code in block like you guys have done?
I want to put the result for reference of people. Finally, got it to work. :)

Comment: @EnigmaK Glad to hear that. :-) Just use the toolbar above the text editor, or select your code and press CTRL+K, or indent your code by 4 spaces. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I tried all but I am not able to understand... :( I am going home right now. I will try again tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, the code is as below. Could anyone please edit and format it? 

***
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    strFile = "C:\Users\inkasap\Desktop\temp\IOParams_Backup.xml"

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile)

 
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
     strLine = objFile.ReadLine

Dim re, strLine
 
Set re = New RegExp 

if InStr(strLine,"name=""BIOSCUPP")> 0 Then 

re.Pattern = "\d+"
Set colMatch = re.Execute(strLine) 

For Each objMatch In colMatch  
strLine = Replace(strLine,objMatch.Value,"30")
Next  

end if 
WScript.Echo strLine

Loop
***

Comment: @EnigmaK You can't format code in comments (other than `this` enclosing the text in "`"). But I added your code to your question, where it can be properly formatted.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Thank you. Have a nice time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RegularExpressions` with [`Regex.Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx):

```
Dim str = "There are 10 apples"
Dim regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\d+", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled)
Dim replaced = regex.Replace(str, "5") ' "There are 5 apples" '
```

Edit: Just only seen that you need a vbscript instead of VB.NET approach.

Comment: No problems. Thanks though. :)